# How can I check if an element has a string after the hash sign in an id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to check is if an ID of an element has more than just the hash sign `#`.

I get a value back from a cms that I can't control, and if a user has not inputted a value I get the following in the js file:

```
$('#').click(function(){
   ...
});
```

as opposed to when they provide a value like so:

```
$('#cust_input').click(function(){
   ...
});
```

What I'd like to do is check if there is something after the `#`, and only if there is will the click event be allowed. Otherwise at runtime I get the first code block above where I have a click event that's tied to `#`, which could cause problems elsewhere on the page.

Comment: Where’s your attempt? Such a check is trivial.

Comment: Confused. The js is generated dynamically I'm presuming? Do you want to check on the client side or server side?

Comment: `if (!string.match(/^#$/)) { `

Comment: You've shown us what you get after a variable is evaluated.  What does this look like before it's evaluated?  Something like `$("#" + myVariable)` ?  If so, you just need to inspect myVariable to verify whether or not it's an empty string.

Comment: @devlincarnate that's what I will try, thank you v much

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following syntax:

```
$("#" + myVariable)
```

You can check `myVariable` for an empty string condition:

```
if(myVariable.trim() === "") {
   //do something
}
```

If there will never be a case where myVariable is a space, you can omit `trim()`